# Why does this python decorator refuse to set the setter?

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-descriptors

This is my code:

```
class Property:
    def __init__(self, fget, fset):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self.fget(obj)
    
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        self.fset(obj, value)

class X:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.__x = val

    @Property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        self.__x = int(val)

myx = X(13)
print(myx.x)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File  "/home/izilinux/git/python/property/ex2.py", line 21, in <module>
    class X:
File "/home/izilinux/git/python/property/ex2.py", line 26, in X
    def x(self):
TypeError: Property.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fset'
```

The getter works fine! The problem started once i tried encorporating a setter into the code. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a [pure-Python equivalent of standard `@property` in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#pure-python-equivalents). I suggest you take a look at it and see what you're missing.

Comment: Your `Property`, unlike the built-in `property`, makes `fset` a *required* argument, not an optional argument. It also doesn't supply a `setter` method for creating a new property based on `x` but with a new setter.